# 7zip: "There are data after end of archive"

Tags: 7-zip

When testing an archive file, I got this error:

[image]

What does this mean, and does that implied that some parts of the archive file cannot be extracted?

I use 7z 9.22 beta on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: ask this the developer: http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, I prefer to stay on SU. I'll ping this forum if I still don't find it.

Comment: here you will not get any information. Again ask this the developer i his support forum

Comment: These are really poor comments. You either know the answer or you don't. Telling him to go somewhere else is useless. And putting the answer here is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this error message with an UpdraftPlus database backup file. My fix was to open up the .gz file in Notepad++. Delete the last word 'null' from the file, save it, then reopen it in 7-Zip and extract the file. Tested on two different .gz files. The extracted sql file looks good and imports into MySQL OK.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information!